# Angular evaluating ngStyle expression constantly on mouse move

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am wondering if this is standard behaviour or am I doing something wrong here. Basically I have assigned an a function that returns an observable to ngStyle which is triggered every time on mouse move.

```
file.html


 <svg #image alt="First slide" class="img_carousel"
  [ngStyle] = "{'background': getImageForDocument(document) | async}">
</svg>


file.ts
getImageForDocument(document, matBadge?): Observable<string> {
        const carouselId = document.id;
 return this.store.select(fromStore.getAllImagesForDataObject(carouselId)).pipe(
            map(images => {
                console.log('heree');
 return images[0].svg !== '' ? `center / contain no-repeat url(${images[0].image64Edit})` : `center / contain no-repeat url(${images[0].image64})`;

                }
            })
        );
    }
```

Now I can see the console printed constantly when I even move the mouse on the page. I would expect that this is triggered only when the state in the store gets updated. Instead ngStyle is evaluating the expression constantly ?

Comment: This is why you should never put function calls in templates. Why do you need to pass document to this function? Why not just set it once in onInit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Angular uses the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` change detection strategy.
The default strategy doesn’t assume anything about the application, therefore every time something changes in our application, as a result of various user events, timers, XHR, promises, etc., a change detection will run on all components.

To solve this issue, you can change detection strategy to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This tells Angular that the component only depends on its `@Input()`.

`OnPush` strategy will run change detection only when `@Input()` changed.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-component.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: The issue here is putting a function call in template, especially one that returns an observable. It’s terrible practice and should be avoided. Onpush change detection has a done of benefits but this issue should be fixed at its source

Comment: Completely agree. Function call in template is not a good practice. It can be fixed with a custom `pipe`. `OnPush` should fix issue and code can be improved with `pipe`